# didAddSubview not working in ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios4, loadview

If I create project using a View-based application template in Xcode using the **iPhone SDK version 4.2** and add just this Objective-C code to the ViewController.m, right after | #pragma mark - View lifecycle | it does not trigger the log message in `didAddSubview` --

```
- (void) loadView {
  [super loadView]:
  CGRect frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, 160, 230);
  UIView *newView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
  [self.view addSubview:newView];
}

-(void) didAddSubview:(UIView *) subview {
  NSLog(@"subview added %@", subview);
}
```

Why this doesn't trigger the event handler when run?

Answer (score 4):

`-didAddSubview:` is a method on `UIView`, not on `UIViewController`.

Comment: Yes, thank you!  I created a subclass of UIView, NUIView, and moved the -(void) didAddSubview:(UIView *) subview {
  NSLog(@"subview added %@", subview);
}
to NUIView.m.  Then I changed the class of the UIView in the ViewController.xib from UIView to NUIView.  Still, it did not trigger the method.